# Where to download Visual Studio 2017 Community edition from?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I Googled "download Visual Studio 2017" and was taken to [this page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), which, at the present time, looks *somewhat* like this. I have edited out some elements on the page to make all the parts relevant to my question fit in one graphic.

[image]

Clicking the **Older Versions** button at the bottom of the page takes me to [this other page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) that looks like the picture below.

[image]

Clicking the **Download** button on the page above takes me to [this page](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017), which reads as follows as also depicted in the picture below.

[image]

If I click the **Visual Studio Dev Essentials** link, I am taken to [my subscriptions page](https://my.visualstudio.com/subscriptions) that looks like this:

[image]

Now, I don't know where to go from here. I have been using Visual Studio for over 22 years now and all the time doing whatever it asked me to do. If it asked me to put my email somewhere, I did. But I ain't buying no nothing.

So, my question is: where do I get Visual Studio 2017 Community from?

I see other websites claiming to have the download, and I trust that they sure do have good intentions, but I ain't downloading anything from a third-party unless a lot of people vouch for the authenticity of that download.

**Why do I want Visual Studio 2017 when there's Visual Studio 2019 already?**

I already have been using Visual Studio 2019 since the day it was released. The thing is: I wanted to set up [the source code of ASP.NET MVC v5.2.6](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/tree/v3.2.6) on my machine. I tried and it gave me trouble, so I wrote to them team guys. And they wrote back saying it would run only on VS 2017 and not on VS 2019.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for downloads to work at *my.visualstudio.com* you need to have a subscription of some description. The easiest one (and the only one I have associated with my account) is **Visual Studio Dev Essentials**:

[image: The 'My Benefits' page on my.visualstudio.com]

This subscription is **free** and it looks like there's a button captioned 'Join Visual Studio Dev Essentials' at the top of your Subscriptions page that you should be able to click to subscribe. Once you've done this, the Downloads page should lead you to:

[image: The 'Downloads' page showing search results filtered to Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.9)]

You can download from there.

It's worth mentioning that [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/) has quite a few other benefits (including Azure credit in the first month, other Azure freebies for the first year and some other goodies) so it's well worth a look in general.

Comment: It seems currently those links/button redirect you to page like https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15&src=myvs which is supposed to give you the given version. But no matter what `rel` is, you always get VS 2019 installer (i.e. at the moment the latest VS).