# Where in the Visual Studio installer do I find the BuildTools component?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In which **Workload** of the **Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.9** installation would I find the **VS2017 BuildTools** component?

I am looking at the workloads in the installer options and there seems not to be any workload that has such a thing.

I even searched in the component in the **Individual Components** tab also but couldn't find anything matching the exact string.

[image]

The reason I am looking for it is that when I try to build the source code for ASP.NET MVC v5.2.6, I get the error message as follows.

```
> build

Could not find MSBuild.exe. Please install the VS2017 
BuildTools component or a workload that includes it.

*** BUILD FAILED **
```

I had written to the ASP.NET MVC team earlier about this message [before I had installed Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58091113/303685). I had had just Visual Studio 2019 then and they asked that I install Visual Studio 2017.

I already have MS Build at various locations. I had multiple versions of MSBuild even before having installed VS 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 is still available as an online installer. You can get the current version here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please also post how you go to that page?

Comment: Do you mean the full URL instead of just a link?

Comment: No, I meant, "How did you get to that page?" Because clicking that link simply shows me a "Thank you for downloading..." page and the **Download** dialog pops up soon after. So, that's a direct download link to the executable. But what should I do if I wanted to get to that link all by myself?

Comment: I got it from the Downloads section of https://my.visualstudio.com but I used my account. If you have an account simply login and search for Build Tools. If you don't, you can sign up free for the Visual Studio Dev Essentials subscription and that will allow you access to it I think.